# Nancy with Razor: Views are cached, making development really hard

Tags: .net, razor, nancy

I'm new to Nancy and Razor (and MVC). If I make a change to a view I have to restart the application somehow (change web.config, restart dev server etc) for the change to take affect.

I think the cache may be Razor's static dictionary? It stores each compiled view? 
No doubt this is great for production, but how do I turn it off for development?
I want to be able to modify a view, save, build and see the change.

Any advise greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: +1 "Nancy With Razor" - new song title of the week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed for 0.8, but for now you can turn the caching off by adding a line to your bootstrapper's InitializeInternal like this:

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void InitialiseInternal(TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        base.InitialiseInternal(container);
#if DEBUG
        StaticConfiguration.DisableCaches = true;
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: You da Man! At first it didn't work - but once I had renamed my view the cache was off from then on. x1000 thanks.